# Vim markdown navigation with ctags: using 'tagbar' + 'markdown2ctags' with 'vim-pandoc'

Tags: vim, markdown, pandoc, ctags, tagbar

All,

I'd like to be able to use the Vim [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) plugin with [markdown2ctags](https://github.com/jszakmeister/markdown2ctags) to navigate my markdown files.

I haven't been able to automatically generate the tags file because the filetype, per `:set filetype?` is currently set to `pandoc`. That's becaue I have the the [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) plugin installed. However, if I change the filtype to `markdown` everything works.

I have control over two items: my `~/.vimrc` file and my `~/.ctags` file. Does anyone have an idea of how things should be set? I've tried changing *markdown* to *pandoc* in the excerpts below, but that didn't help.

**Edit**: As per the comment by @IngoKarkat, because `markdown2ctags` is handling the creation of my `tags` file, the `.ctags` settings are irrelevant.

From my `~/.vimrc` file... (set as per the [Tagbar instructions](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki#markdown) for markdown files)

```
let g:tagbar_type_markdown = {
    \ 'ctagstype': 'markdown',
    \ 'ctagsbin' : '~/.vim/plugged/markdown2ctags/markdown2ctags.py',
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f - --sort=yes --sro=»',
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 's:sections',
        \ 'i:images'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro' : '»',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 's' : 'section',
    \ },
    \ 'sort': 0
\ }
```

...and my `~/.ctags` file (**Edit**: Unused, but still including)

```
--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.mkd
--regex-markdown=/^#[ \t]+(.*)/\1/h,Heading_L1/
--regex-markdown=/^##[ \t]+(.*)/\1/i,Heading_L2/
--regex-markdown=/^###[ \t]+(.*)/\1/k,Heading_L3/
```

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: So do you want to use `markdown2ctags.py` or `ctags` (with the `~/.ctags`) to generate the tags? I think you have to choose one, and then provide the corresponding TagBar config.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That makes sense. I would like the `markdown2ctags.py` executable script to read the markdown file and create the `tags` file. It looks like the `ctagsbin` variable is pointed at the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few solutions to the problem. I've listed them here in case someone finds them useful.

### Solution 1: Re-define the `pandoc` filetype to the `markdown` filetype

I looked at the `vim-pandoc` [pandoc.txt](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/blob/master/doc/pandoc.txt) file and the solution was there. The relevant information:

```
To enable pandoc functionality for markdown files while using  the markdown
filetype and syntax, use
>
     let g:pandoc#filetypes#handled = ["pandoc", "markdown"]
     let g:pandoc#filetypes#pandoc_markdown = 0

Note: vim-pandoc's developers mostly use pandoc's markdown syntax, so
coverage for it is more complete than for the other filetypes.
```

With the filetype now correctly set, everything works. The `~/.vimrc` should be (with appropriate substitution for your own `ctagsbin` path):

```
let g:pandoc#filetypes#handled = ["pandoc", "markdown"]
let g:pandoc#filetypes#pandoc_markdown = 0

let g:tagbar_type_markdown = {
    \ 'ctagstype': 'markdown',
    \ 'ctagsbin' : '~/.vim/plugged/markdown2ctags/markdown2ctags.py',
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f - --sort=yes --sro=»',
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 's:sections',
        \ 'i:images'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro' : '»',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 's' : 'section',
    \ },
    \ 'sort': 0
\ }
```

### Solution 2: Define a new `pandoc` tagbar type

Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:tagbar_type_pandoc = {
    \ 'ctagstype': 'pandoc',
    \ 'ctagsbin' : '~/.vim/plugged/markdown2ctags/markdown2ctags.py',
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f - --sort=yes --sro=»',
    \ 'kinds' : [
        \ 's:sections',
        \ 'i:images'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro' : '»',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 's' : 'section',
    \ },
    \ 'sort': 0
\ }
```

Everything should work! This is my preferred solution.

### Solution 3: Use the builtin `pandoc` `:TOC` command.

The `vim-pandoc` `:TOC` command produces a navigational menu, however, I don't like it as well as the sidebar tagbar menus. But it is a built in default.